# Error ggplot (Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be finite)

Tags: r, ggplot2

For plotting the data with `ggplot2`, I have faced with following error.
The commands, data and error types are available as following:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(HMn25_30$avg,dt_hmn$dt)

df[3] = c(   "Normal",   "Normal",
             "Normal",
             "Normal",
             "Normal",
             "Normal",
             "Normal",
             "Normal",
             "Normal",
             "Normal",
             "Outlier",
             "Outlier",
             "Outlier",
             "Outlier",
             "Outlier",
             "Outlier",
             "Normal",
             "Outlier",
             "Outlier",
             "Normal",
             "Normal",
             "Outlier",
             "Outlier",
             "Normal",
             "Normal"
)
names(df)[1] <- 'Node 25'
names(df)[3] <-'Results'
df.m <- melt(df, names(df)[2:3], names(df)[1])
df.m$Results <- factor(df.m$Results)
df.m$dt_hmn.dt <- strptime(as.character(df.m$dt_hmn.dt), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
p <- ggplot(df.m, aes(x = dt_hmn.dt, y = value, group = variable, color = variable))
p <- p + scale_shape_manual(values=c(27,20))
p <- p + geom_point(aes(shape = Results), cex=13, color= "blue")
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size=13,color="darkred"))
p <- p + scale_color_manual(values=c("Red"))
p <- p + ylim(-1,8)
p <- p + theme_bw()
p <- p + xlab('Date and Time') 
p <- p + ylab('Temprature') 
p <- p + ggtitle("Temporal Outliers of Node 25 ") + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=3, face="bold", color="black", size=29))
    p
```

And the data are:

```
HMn25_30$avg
 [1]  0.280  0.208 -0.264 -0.480 -0.708 -0.714 -0.498 -0.216  0.126  0.574  1.042  1.086  1.820
[14]  4.570  3.808  7.400  5.572  5.402  6.288  4.966  5.180  2.380  4.710  5.366  4.766

dt_hmn$dt
 [1] 9/29/2007 23:00 9/30/2007 0:00  9/30/2007 1:00  9/30/2007 2:00  9/30/2007 3:00 
 [6] 9/30/2007 4:00  9/30/2007 5:00  9/30/2007 6:00  9/30/2007 7:00  9/30/2007 8:00 
[11] 9/30/2007 9:00  9/30/2007 10:00 9/30/2007 11:00 9/30/2007 12:00 9/30/2007 13:00
[16] 9/30/2007 14:00 9/30/2007 15:00 9/30/2007 16:00 9/30/2007 17:00 9/30/2007 18:00
[21] 9/30/2007 19:00 9/30/2007 20:00 9/30/2007 21:00 9/30/2007 22:00 9/30/2007 23:00
```

I have faced the following error:

```
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be finite
```

Comment: Which of those line gives error message? Could you make this shorter, as now there are too many unnecessary lines (for example with theme()) and also could you use dput(df.m) to provide your data.

Comment: @DidzisElferts, The error is occured at the end line after "p".

Comment: There are many problems in your code but first could be in line where you use striptime() - format= is wrong as your initial dates are in format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M". Also try not to use p<-p+... for each line as so you can't detect problem easily. Plot your plot after each change to see if its works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem in your code is that `format=` in `striptime()` had the wrong argument format - it didn't correspond to actual date format. It should be `format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"`

```
df.m$dt_hmn.dt <- strptime(as.character(df.m$dt_hmn.dt), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Next for the `ggplot()` code - if you set `color="blue"` for all points in `geom_point()` you don't need to use `scale_color_manual()` and also use `color=variable` inside `aes()`. For `scale_shape_manual()` there is no shape `27`, changed it to `17`.

If you use `theme_bw()` then other `theme()` calls should be placed after this line to be sure that `theme_bw()` won't override your parameters.

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(x = dt_hmn.dt, y = value, group = variable)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = Results), cex=13, color= "blue")+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(17,20))+
  ylim(-1,8)+
  theme_bw()+
  xlab('Date and Time') +
  ylab('Temprature')+
  ggtitle("Temporal Outliers of Node 25 ") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=3, face="bold", color="black", size=29))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size=13,color="darkred"))
```

[image]