# Error while knitting R-markdown to pdf: must be a finite number

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, plotrix

Knitting my File produces the error message down below:

[image: Picture of Error]

This is how my File starts:

[image: Start of file]

Unfortunately, I couldn't try anything as I have no idea what the error message has to do with the displayed information.

I hope to knit the document to a pdf once this error has been removed.

My code:

```
library(plotrix) 
p6<-pie3D(rawdata8.2$rawdata8.1, 
          col = hcl.colors(length(data), "Spectral"),
          radius = 1.7, 
          theta = 0.25,  
          shade = 0.5,
          height = 0.3,
          start = pi/1.25, 
          explode = 0.2)
title("Anzahl Ankünfte nach Herkunftsland der Touristen 2020" )
```

Comment: Hi. Can you edit your question to add your code as text please ... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Does the code run in an interactive session e.g. not knitting a doc?

Comment: library(plotrix)

p6<-pie3D(rawdata8.2$rawdata8.1,
      col = hcl.colors(length(data), "Spectral"),
       radius = 1.7,
       theta = 0.25,
       shade = 0.5,
       height = 0.3,
      start = pi/1.25,
       explode = 0.2) +
       title("Anzahl Ankünfte nach Herkunftsland der Touristen 2020" )

Comment: Your're right. It used to work on it's own but it doesn't run anymore in an interactive session

Comment: okay so the error seems to be in `hcl.colors(length(data), "Spectral")`. So step through that. What does `length(data)` give ... is it the value you expect? (ps do this in a fresh R session without loading any previous workspace)

Comment: The problem is probably in your 3Dpie and not in the fact that you are knitting to pdf. Please consider checking [pie3D documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotrix/versions/3.8-2/topics/pie3D). And try to run the code of that particular chunk in your console.

Comment: Check [this example](https://jtr13.github.io/cc19/plotrix-for-complex-visualizations.html#pie3d-example) for instance: did you provide both values and labels for your pie-chart? Does it help to set the radius back to 1? Not sure if it can be higher in user units? Have you defined pi somewhere? Or do you need to call it from a math package?

These are some ideas. I hope it helps. This [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897087/error-ggplot-error-in-seq-int0-to0-from-by-to-must-be-finite) might also help.

Comment: These comments are late in the discussion, because they were an answer before. Thanks to @BenBolker who upvoted me, I can now change it into comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious problem is that you are probably asking for a palette of length 1:

```r
hcl.colors(1, "Spectral")
```

> Error in seq.int(1, by = -2/(n - 1), length.out = n2) :
> 'by' must be a finite number

This happens because `hcl.colors` tries to set up a step size `-2/(n-1)`, which is infinite if `n==1`.

Guessing beyond this what's going on: unless you have explicitly defined an object called `data` in your workspace, R will find the built-in function `data()`: `length(data)` is 1 (as it seems all functions have length 1 - not quite sure what the logic is here ...)

Also keep in mind that if you have a data frame `df`, `length(df)` will give you the number of *columns* — you would need `nrow(df)` to get the number of rows ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in your 3Dpie and not in the fact that you are knitting to pdf.
Please consider checking [pie3D documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotrix/versions/3.8-2/topics/pie3D). And try to run the code of that particular chunk in your console.

Check [this example](https://jtr13.github.io/cc19/plotrix-for-complex-visualizations.html#pie3d-example) for instance: did you provide both values and labels for your pie-chart?
Does it help to set the radius back to 1? Not sure if it can be higher in user units?
Have you defined pi somewhere? Or do you need to call it from a math package?

These are some ideas. I hope it helps.
This [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897087/error-ggplot-error-in-seq-int0-to0-from-by-to-must-be-finite) might also help.

Comment: I've just upvoted this answer so that you will have >50 reputation.  Now that you do, I would (paradoxically) like you to re-post this info as a comment rather than an answer, which is it where it belongs ... (I don't think you will lose the reputation by deleting the answer once you've posted the info as a comment ...)

Comment: Thank you, indeed I tried to make a comment as I realized that it was meant that way, but indeed couldn't bcs of my reputation. Thanks for helping me out!